# insert header row from bat into csv file

Tags: batch-file

I have created a bat file that creates a csv file, please see below

```
@echo off
echo %date%,%time%,%computername%,%username% >> %random%.csv
```

This produces csv file which contains the following data:

```
29/05/2021,15:35:31.10,PC9083,fmartin
```

But I need the bat file to include these headers e.g Date,Time,Host,Name if possible e.g.

```
Date,Time,Host,Name
29/05/2021,15:35:31.10,PC9083,fmartin
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? any info would be greatly appreciated

Many Thanks
John

Comment: Just add another `echo` line where you add the headers, what's the problem?

Comment: Hi SomethingDark, that does not work, the >>%random%  names the file, how do you combine to echo into the bat file ?

Comment: Yes it does! `@(Echo "Date","Time","Host","Name"& Echo "%DATE%","%TIME%","%COMPUTERNAME%","%USERNAME%") 1>"%RANDOM%.csv"`

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to move ahead and use PowerShell, this would work. Using `-UseQuotes AsNeeded` requires PowerShell Core 7+. If you remove `-UseQuotes AsNeeded` it will work with Windows PowerShell 5.1, but every field will be quoted.

```
New-Object psobject -Property ([ordered]@{"Date"=(Get-Date).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy');
    "Time"=(Get-Date).ToString('HH:mm:ss.ff');"Host"=$Env:COMPUTERNAME;"Name"=$Env:USERNAME}) |
    Export-Csv -Path '.\so-createcsv.csv' -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation -UseQuotes AsNeeded
```

If you must keep the code in a cmd.exe batch file script, this could be used. Use `pwsh.exe` for PowerShell Core 6+. Use `powershell.exe` for Windows PowerShell 5 or earlier.

```
pwsh.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "New-Object psobject -Property ([ordered]@{""Date""=(Get-Date).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy');""Time""=(Get-Date).ToString('HH:mm:ss.ff');""Host""=$Env:COMPUTERNAME;""Name""=$Env:USERNAME}) |" ^
        "Export-Csv -Path '.\so-createcsv.csv' -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation -UseQuotes AsNeeded"
```